# Splice in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Is to make a "splice" in a value of "return" of the "Template"

Example:

```
Template.create.values = function () {
  return [{
    'value1': '1',
    'value2': '2',
    'value3': '3',
  }];
};
Template.create.events({
  'click #add': function () {
    Template.create.values.splice(Template.create.values.length, 0, {
      'value1': '1',
      'value2': '2',
      'value3': '3',
    });
  }
});
```

I'm doing a "each" in "Template.create.events", and automatically change the template?

Comment: `Template.create.values` is a function, so you'll need to invoke it and splice (or rather `concat` based on what it looks like you're trying to do) the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a session variable or a reactive-dict instead. For example:

```
var DEFAULT_VALUES = {
  'value1': '1',
  'value2': '2',
  'value3': '3'
};

Session.setDefault('createValues', DEFAULT_VALUES);

Template.create.values = function() {
  // I'm assuming you need this in a template
  return Session.get('createValues');
};

Template.create.events({
  'click #add': function() {
    var data = Session.get('createValues');
    data.push(DEFAULT_VALUES);
    Session.set('createValues', data);
  }
});
```